# Outlook Manifest functional in web Outlook, won't properly install in desktop Outlook

Tags: xml, outlook, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on an Outlook Add-In. I've been working so far in the web version, but my understanding is that a manifest that functions in Web should automatically also function in Desktop.

However, I'm encountering an issue where I install my add-in on the desktop, it succeeds, but then instantly disappears. If I go to the "Get Add-ins" page again and go to My Addins, my addin which I just installed does not show up.

This add-in is fully functional in web outlook, so I'm not at all sure what the issue may be. I've tried validating it using

```
npx office-addin-manifest validate MANIFEST_FILE
```

But it passes this. I've also tried enabling runtime logging, but I just get an empty log file if I install it while logging. I'm not sure where to go from here. I've confirmed that the same issue occurs on another machine.

My suspicion is that it may have something to do with the utilization of VersionOverrides 1.1 (we're using this to support pinning a task pane open), but I have no idea why this would cause an issue in Desktop. Minus the resources section, our buttons/tabs are defined with the VersionOverrides 1.1 section.

Appreciate any suggestions for further debugging!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" 
  xsi:type="MailApp">


  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>d0aa58bd-1618-45ed-a773-9e8353a85215</Id>

  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Test Name</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Onvio Add-In" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Onvio Outlook Add-In For Interaction With Document Management Service"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://img.icons8.com/clouds/2x/cloud-network.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/g_collection_png/standard/256x256/earth.png" />


 <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200"/>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Onvio.PaneButton.Icon" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/FkSShX9.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Onvio.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200" />
        <bt:Url id="Onvio.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Onvio.Pane.Title" DefaultValue="Onvio Side Panel" />
        <bt:String id="Onvio.Pane.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Onvio.Tab.Label" DefaultValue="Onvio Tab Label" />
        <bt:String id="Onvio.OpenedMessageTools.Label" DefaultValue="Onvio.OpenedMessageTools.Label" />
        <bt:String id="Onvio.ComposeMessageTools.Label" DefaultValue="Onvio.ComposeMessageTools.Label" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Onvio.Pane.Description" DefaultValue="Onvio Side Panel Description" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residDescription" />
      <Requirements>
        <Sets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0">
          <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
        </Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="Message" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1">
                  <Label resid="Onvio.ComposeMessageTools.Label" />

                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Onvio.ComposePane.Button">
                    <Label resid="Onvio.Pane.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="Onvio.Pane.Title" />
                      <Description resid="Onvio.Pane.Description" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Onvio.PaneButton.Icon" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Onvio.PaneButton.Icon" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Onvio.PaneButton.Icon" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Onvio.Taskpane.Url" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <CustomTab id="Onvio.OpenedMessageTools.Tabs">
                <Group id="Onvio.OpenedMessageTools.Group" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1">
                  <Label resid="Onvio.OpenedMessageTools.Label" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Onvio.Pane.Button">
                    <Label resid="Onvio.Pane.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="Onvio.Pane.Title" />
                      <Description resid="Onvio.Pane.Description" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Onvio.PaneButton.Icon" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Onvio.PaneButton.Icon" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Onvio.PaneButton.Icon" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Onvio.Taskpane.Url" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
                <Label resid="Onvio.Tab.Label" />
              </CustomTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Are you using the same mailbox account for OWA(web) and desktop Outlook?  Once an addin is installed for a user, it should work across mailbox.  Another possibility is that desktop Outlook is not of the version to support your addin.  Could you share the build number and platform for Outlook? And whether you are using Office365 or Exchange on-premises mailbox?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same mailbox account for OWA and desktop Outlook. We're using Office365, and my desktop build is 'Version 1902 (Build 11328.20468)' on Windows 10 64 bit. Let me know if you need any other info!

Comment: Could you please share your manifest?

Comment: Just edited my original post to include it.

Comment: Move the Resources from VersionOverridesV1_0 to VersionOverridesV1_1, it should come after the Hosts object. This worked for us in Outlook Desktop and OWA.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! 

One note though, I sanitized some of the xml before submitting it. Part of the sanitation involved removing an internal url path that was being used temporarily for the icons. Having an internal url path for the icon led to the same problem on Desktop, even though it worked in web.